# parse files at node server uploaded via formdata

Tags: node.js

I am using formdata to post some data and files using axios at client as follows.

```
var formdata = new FormData();
formdata.append('title', shopTitle);
    formdata.append('ownedby', shopOwner);
    formdata.append('locality', shopLocality);
formdata.append('selectedFile', file);

axios.post('http://localhost:3000/businesses/', formdata, {headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
      }})
      .then(function (response) {
        console.log(response);
      })
      .catch(function (error) {
          console.log('error occured..');
        console.log(error);
      });
```

Now at server I am using formidable in order to parse formdata as follows-

```
var express = require('express');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var formidable = require('formidable');
var fs = require('fs');

// create express app
var app = express();
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }))
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.post('/businesses', function(req, res){

var form = new formidable.IncomingForm();
form.parse(req, function(err, fields, files){
                        console.log('parsing fields..');
                        // selectedFile is found in fields and not in files
                        console.log(fields);
                        console.log('parsing files..');
                        console.log(files);                       
                        });
});
```

Here at server, the selected file is found inside "fields" and not in "files". console.log(fields) statement prints the output as

```
{   title: 'avani sweets',
  ownedby: 'avani',
  locality: 'sec 31',
  selectedFile: 'data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZ..............
}
```

Now I want to save this image (which is represented by selectedFile) inside a directory. How can I do that? I will be very much thankful if I can get some help. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand, you have disabled the file-uploading by providing the call-back function. If yo take a look at the example they have in their GitHub-repo, not the one in their README.MD, https://github.com/felixge/node-formidable/blob/master/example/upload.js, you will se a very different approach to handling the upload.

```
...snip...
    } else if (req.url == '/upload') {
    var form = new formidable.IncomingForm(),
        files = [],
        fields = [];

    form.uploadDir = os.tmpdir();

    form
      .on('field', function(field, value) {
        console.log(field, value);
        fields.push([field, value]);
      })
      .on('file', function(field, file) {
        console.log(field, file);
        files.push([field, file]);
      })
      .on('end', function() {
        console.log('-> upload done');
        res.writeHead(200, {'content-type': 'text/plain'});
        res.write('received fields:\n\n '+util.inspect(fields));
        res.write('\n\n');
        res.end('received files:\n\n '+util.inspect(files));
      });
    form.parse(req);
  } else {

...snip...
```

As you see, they rely set an upload directory, and use event-listeners, rather than supplying `.parse(...)` with a callback, to get the files and fields. In the `.on('file',...)` listener they push the file with its field name into the array containing the files, so you can find them in the filesystem.

The upload is finished in the `.on('end',...)` listener, and then ypu can kick off any other jobs you need, saving the fields and file paths to a database for instance.

I hope this helps you get back on track in your project!

---

#### EDIT

Apparently I misread the part about formdata. I thought you meant multipart/formdata as the numerous other posts online do.

What you need to do instead, if you can't make axios send in traditional format, is to take the base64 endcoded part of the `selectedFile` and save to a new file.

```
var raw = fields.selectedFile.split(";");
var imageType = raw[0].split("/")[1];
if(imageType == "jpeg"){
    imageType = "jpg";
}

var encodedFile = raw[1].split(",")[1];

require("fs").writeFile(`someFileName.${imageType}`, encodedFile, 'base64',(err) => {
    console.log(err);
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the information. But it did not work. The 'file' event is never getting called. I am getting the 'selectedFile' with its value in the 'field' event. Actually I am not worried about the file event not getting called because I am getting my file inside the 'field' event. The only thing is I am not able to parse it in such a way that I could store it somewhere at my server. I hope I made myself clear. Thanks

Comment: Also I went to the link you provided https://github.com/felixge/node-formidable/blob/master/example/upload.js. The method for sending data and file to the server is different there. They use the <form> element in order to send multi part form data but I am using axios where I create an object of FormData, append data and files in to it and post this object via axios post API. At server, I am receiving everything inside field event handler and nothing in the file event handler.

Comment: @Manish I've updated my answer to incorporate an algorithm for parsing the encoded file-string. I assume a Node.JS version supporting ES6